# spark horovod on k8s

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-ml

Since spark 3.0 introduces Horovod estimator, I'm wondering how does it compare to using horovod directly using horovod's original mpi-run? and also wonder that can be run on top of k8s scheduler? Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Can you make your question more specific. It is currently rather broad and difficult to answer.